# Angular 2 Component In Component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I want to use component in component.
For example;

First, I will create a common ModalComponent component.
[image]

And I want to use this component with my other components.
For Example;
[image]

Comment: so what's the question, issue? error ?

Comment: How can I other component content (customer-card, product-card e.g) add to modal component modal-body div? (<!--Here is dynamic-->)

Comment: @anoop thank you. ng-content is solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ng-content></ng-content>` directive is solved my problem.

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```